# plsql update trigger that restricts update if client is not active

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CLIENTS_DISCOUNT
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    OF DISCOUNT
    ON CLIENTS
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (NEW.ISACTIVE = 'N')
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
    (-20001, 'CUSTOMER IS NOT ACTIVE')
    END IF;
END;
```

Sample clients table:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (ClientID, ClientName, Discount, isActive, PrimarySiteID) AS
SELECT  1, '21st Century Fox',  5, 'Y',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Erikson',          10, 'N',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'It Smart Group',    5, 'Y',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'UPC',               5, 'N',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Telekom',          15, 'Y',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'ExxonMobil',       10, 'N',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Biolife Grup',     20, 'Y',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Apple Inc.',        0, 'N',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'AECOM',             5, 'Y',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Metro',            10, 'N', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

I want to create a PL/SQL before insert or update trigger that restricts clients that are not active to getting their discount updated. I am not sure if I need to declare something.

Comment: OK. great.  What have you attempted?  MySQL is not Oracle.  You mention PL/SQL in your title which is Oracle.  Which database are you referring to? Remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: I am using oracle and I am trying to determine if I need to declare something.

Comment: Please don't post links to images.  People will not open them. Post in the question as text/table or from database DDL statement.    You also need to show the DDL for the DISCOUNT table.

Comment: thanks for the advice, very new here! hopefully it's better now

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if I need to declare something.

No, you do not need the `DECLARE` keyword if you are not going to declare any variables.

[A trigger has the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B):

> [image: Trigger syntax]
>
> #### trigger_body ::=
>
> [image: Trigger body syntax]

The [syntax for a PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D) is:

> [image: PL/SQL block syntax]

Which demonstrates that the `DECLARE` is optional.

---

All you need to do is check `IF` the `:NEW.isActive` (or `:OLD.isActive`) equals `N` and if it does `THEN` use [`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1) to generate a user-defined error and prevent the insert/update.

Comment: okay good, that's what I was trying to use, thanks for the helping me understand!